# Wordpress Blank pages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ftp

I can't find out why the pages return blank or show no code.
   A company is asking me for doing its SEO.
    Now the problem that i face is that the site is a one-pager.
    When i create a new page in Wordpress it shows a blank page and there is no code in it.
    So the home page is working but everything after the / returns blank `(no errors / no code nothing.`
    The theme is hand made, i have the FTP login but i can't figure out why its not working to create a new page.
    I already added the `.htaccess` file because it wasn't there.

Comment: Do you have index.php file in your theme files?

Comment: yes the homepage is working but all new sites i create return blank (also 404 pages don't show up

Comment: there is a index.php but that one is empty, he pulls out the code from the front-page.php @TomislavSvecak

Comment: If you put some random text into index.php and check that new page you created will you get anything?

Comment: @TomislavSvecak that works, thanks! but now al the sub pages shows the same.

Comment: well I would suggest creating a custom template for whatever you need. e.g. if you want all pages to show content from wordpress you could add `<?php the_content(); ?>` that should give you page content. Depends on what do you need obviously per template :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of, what I assume, bad templating.
It seems like the author created a front page template and nothing else.

You need to write some more template files in order to get this theme working properly and respecting the Wordpress Theme guidelines.

Common WordPress template files #Common WordPress template files

Below is a list of some basic theme templates and files recognized by WordPress.

- index.php

  style.css

  rtl.css

  comments.php

  front-page.php

  home.php

  header.php

  singular.php

  single.php

  single-{post-type}.php

  archive-{post-type}.php

  page.php

  page-{slug}.php

  category.php

  tag.php

  taxonomy.php

  author.php

  date.php

  archive.php

  search.php

  attachment.php

  image.php

  404.php

There is a decent guide on this issue on Wordpress' [theme handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/).

Comment: Following the official handbook should result to no issues. Everything is explained in the link given.

Comment: Any news @Bitcoin ?